# Running a powershell script from another one. Test-path giving false

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to run a script with admin rights by users. So I created 2 scripts where a user runs the first script which will call the second script with start-process with admin credentials. I am passing currently logged in user ID and user profile from first script to second script as arguments to make use of them in the second script. However everything is fine but getting error when accessing user's documents folder in the second script using a variable to the path.

First script as below.

```
    $currentusername = $env:USERNAME
    $currentuserprofile = $env:USERPROFILE
    $adminusername = "domain\admin"
    $adminPassword = 'pwd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
    $credential = New-Object 
    System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($adminusername, $adminPassword)
    $scriptpath = "path to second script.ps1"
    Start-Process -filepath PowerShell.exe -Credential $credential -argumentlist "-noexit", "-executionpolicy bypass","-file $scriptpath",$currentusername,$currentuserprofile
```

Second Script.ps1

```
    param (
    #$currentusername = $args[3],
    $currentuserprofile = $args[5]
    )
    $UserDir = "$currentuserprofile\Documents\"
    Test-Path $UserDir
```

this test-path $UserDir is giving false.
Can anyone have had this issue or help me on to overcome this?

Comment: what is $currentuserprofile returning? In your case it should be null. Just check that first

Answer (score 1):

When you pass in argument to powershell.exe along with `-file` only the arguments **AFTER** the file path are passed onto the script. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-5.1)

So technically, in your 2nd script, you only have the following arguments:

```
$args[0] # $currentusername
$args[1] # $currentuserprofile
```

That being said, generally you don't use $args and param together. It's one or the other.

you can either do this:

```
$currentusername = $args[0]
$currentuserprofile = $args[1]

$UserDir = "$currentuserprofile\Documents\"
Test-Path $UserDir
```

OR

```
param (
 $currentusername,
 $currentuserprofile
)

$UserDir = "$currentuserprofile\Documents\"
Test-Path $UserDir
```

Comment: what's the error? Can you copy and paste as is or provide a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Even though you're passing admin user credentials, by default, the process is not started with elevated permissions, add -verb RunAs to the start-process to achieve that.

Comment: not actually admin user  though. I am using a different user account having elevated permissions. It is working.